# biblatex-dw custom bibliography formatting @incollectioneditor names should be ordered last name - first name

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, biblatex-dw

In order to meet the publication criteria for a book, I need some custom formatting for the bibliography, especially @incollection items:

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    and={/},
    page={},
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
    editor = {{ Hg\adddot }} ,
    editors = {{ Hg\adddot }}
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}

    @book{b2,
        year = {2014},
        title = {Redefreiheit: Öffentliche Debatten der Bevölkerung im Herbst 1989},
        address = {Leipzig},
        edition = {1. Aufl.},
        publisher = {Leipziger Uni-Vlg},
        isbn = {386583888X},
        editor = {Ahbe, Thomas and Stiehler, Volker and Hofmann, Michael},
        shorttitle = {Redefreiheit}
    }

    @incollection{bauer,
        xref = {schwobel},
        author = {Bauer, Gisa},
        title = {Transformationen des Religiösen: Die historisch-materialistische Geschichtsschreibung in der DDR als Heilsgeschichte},
        volume = {39},
        series = {VWGTh},
        editor = {Schwöbel, Christoph},
        booktitle = {Geschichte und Gott},
        address = {Leipzig},
        shorttitle = {Transformationen}
    }

    @book{schwobel,
        title = {Geschichte und Gott: XV. Europäischer Kongress für Theologie},
        address = {Leipzig},
        volume = {39},
        series = {VWGTh},
        editor = {Schwöbel, Christoph},
        shorttitle = {Geschichte}
    }
    @book{bulischop.2006,
        author = {Bulisch, Jens},
        year = {2006},
        title = {Evangelische Presse in der DDR},
        address = {Göttingen},
        volume = {43},
        publisher = {Vandenhoeck und Ruprecht},
        isbn = {3525557442},
        series = {AKZG},
        shorttitle = {Presse}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib}
\begin{document}
    text \footcite{bulischop.2006} text.
    text \footcite{bauer} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I would need the following change to bibliography formatting see picture:

[image: descriptive image]

1. For @incollection items, the editor names should be ordered last name - first name, and the last name should **not** be in capitals, while the **author** last name should still be in capitals

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. Even if the issues seem small it is much easier for the people answering your question as well as for future visitors who want to benefit from your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unsafe (but short) solution for the name order is

```
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{bytranslator}{family-given}
```

Safer, but longer, is

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareNameAlias{useeditor}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{usetranslator}{family-given}
\renewbibmacro*{useeditor}{%
  \def\bbx@firstnamefont{}%
  \def\bbx@namefont{}%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{editor}
    {\ifbool{bbx:edbyidem}
      {\midsentence*\bibstring[\mkidem]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
       \addspace}%
      {\printnames[useeditor]{editor}%
       \usebibmacro{editorstringpunct}%
       \savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}%
    {\printnames[useeditor]{editor}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstringpunct}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}%
   \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
   \clearname{editor}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}

\renewbibmacro*{usetranslator}{%
  \def\bbx@firstnamefont{}%
  \def\bbx@namefont{}%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{translator}
    {\ifbool{bbx:edbyidem}
      {\midsentence*\bibstring[\mkidem]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
       \addspace}%
      {\printnames[usetranslator]{translator}%
       \usebibmacro{editorstringpunct}%
       \savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}%
    {\printnames[usetranslator]{translator}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstringpunct}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}%
   \usebibmacro{translatorstrg}%
   \clearname{translator}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}
\makeatother
```

The latter code block also contains a way to suppress small caps for editors.